# Audio classification in Android for an audio clip as input (using YAMNet TensorFlow lite model)

Tags: android, audio, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I've used this audio classification app and I really like it:
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/audio_classification/android/

This example use a phone mic to start recording (**live recording**) and classify the input.

Here is the code to use this model:

```
val model = YamnetClassification.newInstance(this)

// Creates inputs for reference.
val audioClip = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(15600), DataType.FLOAT32)
audioClip.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)

// Runs model inference and gets result.
val outputs = model.process(audioClip)
val scores = outputs.scoresAsTensorBuffer
```

I have an **audio clip** (for example, in R.raw.s1.wav) and I want to take it as input and classify it with the help of the YAMNet model.

How to update above example to take an audio clip as input instead of the live recording? I think the audio clip need to be converted to **ByteBuffer**?how this conversion can be done for the audio clip?

Comment: Can you provide the file where this code is ? Since I cloned the repo but couldn't find it in the dir that you provided

Comment: when you add the tensorflow lite model to Android Studio, you can see this code by clicking on the model. https://tfhub.dev/google/lite-model/yamnet/classification/tflite/1

Answer (score 0):

the same as python code in YamNet doc(https://www.kaggle.com/models/google/yamnet/frameworks/tensorFlow2/variations/yamnet/versions/1?tfhub-redirect=true):

```
public static void mp3ToPcm(Context context, File mp3File, Mp3ToPcmListener listener) {
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "TFL::predictMp3, mp3ToPcm");

            String pcmUri = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + mp3File.getName() + ".pcm";
            boolean createRes = new File(pcmUri).createNewFile();

            String mp3Uri = mp3File.getAbsolutePath();
            int res = WcvCodec.decodeMp3ToPcm(mp3Uri, pcmUri);

            if (res == 0) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onFile(pcmUri);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "TFL::predictMp3, mp3ToPcm, Exception = " + e);
        }
    }



public static void decodePcm(String pcmUri, DecodePcmListener listener) {
        File pcmFile = null;
        FileInputStream pcmFis = null;

        try {
            //Log.d(TAG, "TFL::predictMp3, decodePcm");

            List<PredictPcmRes> pcmResList = new ArrayList<>();
            //Log.d(TAG, "TFL::predictMp3, decodePcm, new pcmResList");

            pcmFile = new File(pcmUri);
            pcmFis = new FileInputStream(pcmFile);

            String pcmName = pcmFile.getName();
            pcmName = pcmName.substring(MathUtils.clamp(pcmName.length() - 15, 0, pcmName.length()), pcmName.length());
            Log.i(WcvCodec.TAG, "decodePcm, pcmName = " + pcmName);

            long totalBytes = pcmFile.length();
            Short[] pcmShorts = new Short[SAMPLE_SIZE];

            long sliceCnt = totalBytes / DATA_CAPACITY;
            int sliceIdx = 0;
            Log.i(WcvCodec.TAG, "decodePcm"
                    + ", sliceCnt = " + sliceCnt
                    + "= res.totalBytes / 4 * 8000L = "
                    + totalBytes + " / " + (4 * 8000L)
            );

            int accRead = 0;

            byte[] twoBytes = new byte[2];
            for (int idx = 0, idxForSeconds = 0, read; (read = pcmFis.read(twoBytes, 0, 2)) != -1; idx += read) {

                accRead += read;

                if (idx <= 10 /*|| idx > 1269680*/) {
                    Log.i(WcvCodec.TAG, "decodePcm"
                            + ", idx=" + idx
                            + ", totalBytes=" + totalBytes
                            + ", pcmName=" + pcmName
                    );
                }

                // order with LITTLE_ENDIAN
                ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(twoBytes);
                ByteBuffer orderedBuffer = byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                short orderedShort = orderedBuffer.getShort();

                // left channel only
                if (idx % 4 == 0) {
                    pcmShorts[idxForSeconds++ % pcmShorts.length] = orderedShort;

                    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                        if (idx >= 6000 && idx < 6020) {
                            Log.i(WcvCodec.TAG, "decodePcm"
                                    + ", pcmName=" + pcmName
                                    + ", idx=" + idx
                                    + ", [0x" + Integer.toHexString(twoBytes[0] & 0xff)
                                    + " 0x" + Integer.toHexString(twoBytes[1] & 0xff)
                                    + "] = " + orderedShort
                            );
                        }
                    }

                    //Log.i(WcvCodec.TAG, "decodePcm" + ", idxForSeconds=" + idxForSeconds);
                    if (idxForSeconds % frame_of_audio == 0) {
                        sliceIdx += 1;

                        if (listener != null) {

                            PredictPcmRes res = new PredictPcmRes();
                            res.pcmUri = pcmUri;
                            res.pcmShorts = pcmShorts;
                            res.durIdx = sliceIdx;
                            res.durCnt = sliceCnt;
                            Log.d(TAG, "TFL::predictMp3, decodePcm, " + res.durIdx + " / " + res.durCnt);

                            listener.run(res, pcmResList);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Log.i(WcvCodec.TAG, "decodePcm"
                    + ", sliceIdx=" + sliceIdx
                    + ", sliceCnt=" + sliceCnt
                    + ", accRead=" + accRead
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "TFL::predictMp3, Exception = " + e);
        } finally {
            if (pcmFis != null) {
                ReleaseUtil.release(pcmFis);
            }
            if (pcmFile != null) {
                boolean res = pcmFile.delete();
            }
        }
    }



    public static void predictPcm(PredictPcmRes res, Context context, PredictPcmListener listener) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "TFL::predictPcm, pcm length = " + res.pcmShorts.length);

            // pcm to normalized floats
            float[] normalizedFloats = new float[res.pcmShorts.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < res.pcmShorts.length; i++) {
                short ps = res.pcmShorts[i] != null ? res.pcmShorts[i] : 0;
                normalizedFloats[i] = 1f * ps / (Short.MAX_VALUE + 1);
            }
            res.normalizedFloats = normalizedFloats;
            Log.d(TAG, "TFL::predictPcm, normalizedFloats length = " + res.normalizedFloats.length);

            // do predict on normalized floats
            ModelExecutor executor = new ModelExecutor(context, false);
            Pair<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<Float>> pair = executor.execute(normalizedFloats);
            res.pair = pair;

            if (Lg.DEBUG) {
                Log.i(TAG, "TFL::predictPcm, pair first = " + pair.getFirst().toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "TFL::predictPcm, pair second = " + pair.getSecond().toString());
            }

            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onSuccess();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "TFL::predictMp3, predictPcm, Exception = " + e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save your audio file in `assets` folder, then you can retrieve it and covert to `ByteBuffer` using a FIleChannel:

```
override fun loadMappedFileFromAssets(context Context, filePath: String): ByteBuffer?
    = try {
        context.assets.openFd(filePath).use { fileDescriptor ->
            FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.fileDescriptor).use { inputStream ->
                inputStream.channel.use { fileChannel ->
                    val startOffset = fileDescriptor.startOffset
                    val declaredLength = fileDescriptor.declaredLength
                    fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (ex: Throwable) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
```

Then just use this ByteByffer and pass to Tensorflow model